# Jenkins_ getting compilation error (cannot find symbol) for maven project causing build failure

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, svn

I am getting compilation error when I run jenkins build. Mine is a maven project and the code comes from svn, it works well locally, Only if I run it on Jenkins I get compilation error:

/C:/Users/xyz/.jenkins/workspace/RegressionSuite/src/test/java/com/aptimus/xyz/ui/pages/xyz.java:[329,32] cannot find symbol

symbol:   method waitForElementVisiblexpath(java.lang.String)

The above mentioned method is present and it's all working fine locally, Only on Jenkins it's causing some issue, Please do help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange,you can check a few things:

- The branch you are checking out in jenkins is same as you have checked in your local
- There can be some uncommitted file which is there on your local and not in the repo
- The line mentioned[329,32] contains comment, because sometimes this issue happens with special character in comments.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer...as suggested by you , I verified all the three things , but it all looks good,  also my compiler and surefire plugins are set to latest version and my source and target in pom file is set to 1.7....I am not sure what may be causing this  issue.

Comment: Are you pointing to correct pom in jenkins maven build? Have you ever been able to make a successful build of this code,prior to this issue?

Comment: Yes I am pointing to correct pom.xml file, I was able to make a successful build locally through maven (eclipse).

Comment: So this you haven't been able to create even a single build of this project structure through jenkins?

Comment: I got it!!....I imported the code from svn to a different workspace and there I could see some compilation errors on eclipse, fixed those and  then committed the code.....all is good now...Thanks all.